# How to regex match with a run-time parameter?

Tags: regex, parameters, code-injection

I've got a string entered by the user, and I want to embed that string into a regex. Is there a way to embed a parameter value in a similar way to parameters in SQL queries?

For example, I could do this:

```
string myRegex = "[abc]" + myParameter + "[xyz]";
```

but this would not work because `myParameter` could contain regex special characters.

SQL injection was fixed by using parameters. How do I do the same with regexes?

Note that myParameter could contain any character from the whole of unicode except maybe control characters, although I would hope a general purpose solution would allow even control characters to be matched.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on the regular expression engine at hand I believe.

In Java you typically do

```
"[abc]" + Pattern.quote(myParameter) + "[xyz]"
```

or (if `myParameter` doesn't contain `\E`) you could do

```
"[abc]\\Q" + myParameter + "\\E[xyz]"
```

Comment: In your second example, what will happen if `myParameter` contains `\\E` inside?